# Toggle height of a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with the class name 'content' and it has some content. I have set its height to 80px. height:80px; overflow:hidden;

I have a button with class name 'button' and I am trying to toggle and make the height auto or remove the height 80 px on click and then once clicked again take the div back to 80px.

I am also trying to have the button change its value in-between show more/show less

Thanks

Comment: Add custom class for the div and toggle it `$(button).toggleClass('customClass');`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/pavlito/dhcg427y/#base

Answer (score 1):

```
.height {
    height: 80px;
}

$(".button").click(function(){
    $("div.container").toggleClass("height");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for to get rid to much javascript,

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
  $('.content').toggleClass('changeHeight');
  $('.button > *').toggleClass('show hide')
})
```

```css
.show {display: block;}
.hide {display: none;}
.content {height: 80px; background: red; color: white;}
.content.changeHeight {height: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div>Some contents</div>
</div>
<button class="button">
  <span class="show">Show</span>
  <span class="hide">Hide</span>
</button>
```

If you want to animate it, you can add `transition` to class `content`.

Also there is another useful way to toggle class to parent element containing both these elements (button and div).

Answer (score 1):

Check this code snippet. Hope it helps!

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function(){
 var $btn = $(".btn");
  var $content = $(".content");
  $content.toggleClass("sized");

  if($btn.text() == "Show More"){
   $btn.text("Show Less")
  } else if($btn.text() == "Show Less"){
   $btn.text("Show More")
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.content{
  height: 80px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.btn{
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #d63333;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sized{
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content sized">Hello World!</div>
<div class="btn">Show More</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is something that may help you

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#button").on("click", function (){
        if ($(".content").height() == 0) {
           $(".content").animate(
               {height: "80px"});
           }
        else if ($(".content").height() == 80) {
           $(".content").animate({height: "0px"});
           }
        });
    });
```